# Ant exclude does not exclude directory

Tags: java, ant

I want to package some specific libraries into a package. Therefore, i want to below ant task:

```
 <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="bin"/>
  <property name="target"  location="c:\\temp\\invoke.jar"/>
 <target name="dist" depends="compile"
        description="generate the distribution" >
    <echo message="Start jar java.lang.invoke package.."/>
    <delete file="${target}" />
    <jar destfile="${target}" basedir="${build}">
        <fileset dir="${build}/">
            <include name="java/lang/invoke/*.*" />
            <exclude name="com/** javax/** org/** sun/**" />
      </fileset>
    </jar>
  </target>
```

The directory structure is

```
c:\....\J9 JCL>dir bin
 Directory of C:\...\J9 JCL\bin

03/10/2015  05:42 PM    <DIR>          com
03/10/2015  05:42 PM    <DIR>          java
03/10/2015  05:42 PM    <DIR>          javax
07/20/2014  06:44 PM             2,173 notices.txt
03/10/2015  05:42 PM    <DIR>          org
07/20/2014  06:44 PM             1,056 rcm.xsd
03/10/2015  05:42 PM    <DIR>          sun
07/20/2014  06:44 PM               230 tags.properties
```

AS shown in the "dist" task, only the library in

> bin/java/lang/invoke

is required for jar task. But after running, it seems both include and exclude does not work. Is there any wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out, just change the target section and removed the fileset

```
<target name="dist" depends="compile"
        description="generate the distribution" >
    <echo message="Start jar java.lang.invoke package.."/>
    <delete file="${target}" />
    <jar destfile="${target}" 
         basedir="${build}"
         include name="java/lang/invoke/*.*" 
         exclude name="com/** javax/** org/** sun/**"
    </jar>
</target>
```

Comment: you want to use `includes` rather than `include name`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your excludes don't seem to work and faljbour's answer does is that the nested `exclude` element works and the `excludes` attributes work in different ways.  The attribute splits its value at commas or spaces so you can specify multiple of them.  The element does not - after all you may want to specify a pattern containing spaces.  So you get a single pattern of "com/** javax/** org/** sun/**" which certainly doesn't match anything.

```
<jar destfile="${target}" basedir="${build}">
    <fileset dir="${build}"
        includes="java/lang/invoke/*.*"
        excludes="com/** javax/** org/** sun/**" />
  </fileset>
</jar>
```

or

```
<jar destfile="${target}" basedir="${build}">
    <fileset dir="${build}/">
        <include name="java/lang/invoke/*.*" />
        <exclude name="com/**"/>
        <exclude name="javax/**"/>
        <exclude name="org/**"/>
        <exclude name="sun/**" />
  </fileset>
</jar>
```

would bot work the same way.  BTW, you can leave off the `**` as Ant automatically translates the pattern `foo/` to `foo/**`.